# ContentDialog hidden behind soft keyboard UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I developed an UWP application that's having a wrong behavior on new version of Windows 10. In my application i have some ContentDialog with some TextBox inside them and when the soft-keyboard is shown it should push upwards the contentdialog but in new build of windows 10 this is not happening, anyone know why?
Here is a sample of my ContentDialog code:

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="ManImp.CDEseguiOdM"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ManImp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
MaxHeight="{StaticResource ContentDialogMaxHeight}"
MaxWidth="{StaticResource ContentDialogMaxWidth}"
Margin="0"
Padding="0">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationBackGroudColor}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <!--0-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <!--0-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <!--1-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <!--2-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <!--3-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stckLabelFirma" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblFirma" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0">
        <InkToolbar InitialControls="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvasFirma}" >
            <InkToolbarEraserButton />
            <InkToolbarBallpointPenButton />
        </InkToolbar>

        <Grid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Image Name="imgFirma" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
            <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvasFirma" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></InkCanvas>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stckDatiSupProd" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--0-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--1-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--2-->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10,5,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblCID"  VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF034872" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCID" BorderBrush="Red" MaxLength="8" TextChanged="txtCID_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,10,5,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblAlias"  VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF034872" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtAlias" BorderBrush="Red" TextChanged="txtAlias_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblPIN"  VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF034872" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPIN" BorderBrush="Red" PasswordChanged="txtPIN_PasswordChanged" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"></PasswordBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblErrore" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--0-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <!--1-->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="btnAnnulla" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,30,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnAnnulla_Click"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnConfFirmaSupProd" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnConfFirmaSupProd_Click"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnConfFirmaOperatore" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnConfFirmaOperatore_Click"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me on which windows 10 version did you meet this behavior? And on which windows 10 version that your code works correctly?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Hi, the window 10 version where i am having this behavior is 19041 and where its working fine is the 14393

Comment: Have you tried it on other devices like 18363 or 17763? What is the behavior on these windows 10 versions?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I dont have any devices with those version so i cant check it out

Comment: I made a test about this in Build 19042 which is known as 20H2 and I got different behavior. I turned my device into Tablet mode first. Then I created a new UWP app that will show a `ContentDialog`. When I want to type something to the `TextBox` in the `ContentDialog`, the `ContentDialog` will move upwards when the on-screen keyboard is shown. Build 14393 is an earlier version that a long time ago. I'd suggest you run the app on devices with the latest version of Windows 10 to check the behavior.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT what is the target of your uwp application? because i need it to be 14393 since we have some old tablet in circulation and they cant be upgraded.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I changed the target version to Build 14393 and I could reproduce this issue now. I made some more tests and find that if the target version is Build 16299, then the `ContentDialog` will move upwards when the on-screen keyboard is shown. As you know, my device is running windows 10 20H2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an issue related to the old SDK that when the app is targeting old versions like 14393.

If you really want to achieve this behavior on all versions of Windows 10. I'd suggest you handle the showing and hiding events manually via [InputPane.Showing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.showing?view=winrt-19041) and [InputPane.Hiding Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.hiding?view=winrt-19041). And then you might need to customize a `PopUp` control that looks like a `ContentDialog`. We can't change the position of the `ContentDialog`, because it is handled by the system. But we could change the position of a `PopUp` control.

When the on-screen keyboard is shown, the showing event will be fired and you could try to manually move your `PopUp` control upwards. When the keyboard is hidden, just move the `PopUp` control back to its original position.

Here is the sample code about how to handle the show and hide event:

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        InputPane currentInputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
        // Subscribe to Showing/Hiding events
        currentInputPane.Showing += OnShowing;
        currentInputPane.Hiding += OnHiding;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        InputPane currentInputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
        // Unsubscribe from Showing/Hiding events
        currentInputPane.Showing -= OnShowing;
        currentInputPane.Hiding -= OnHiding;
    }

    void OnShowing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }

    void OnHiding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

You could also get information about the touch keyboard here: [Respond to the presence of the touch keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/respond-to-the-presence-of-the-touch-keyboard#handling-the-showing-and-hiding-events)